# What's the proper method of installing a plugin during unit testing?

Tags: testing

I am testing a plugin that depends on WooCommerce. In order to properly test the integration, I need WooCommerce installed in the WordPress test application.

I tried installing the plugin using `wp-cli` via the `install_wp_tests` script:

```
wp plugin install woocommerce --activate --allow-root --path=$WP_CORE_DIR
```

This kicks out an error:

```
Error: 'wp-config.php' not found.
```

From what I can tell, the test configuration file is in `/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php`. From reading the `wp-cli` docs, I don't see any method to specify the path to the configuration file.

How can I install WooCommerce during my test setup process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then there's the *Composer* approach described [here](https://stevegrunwell.com/blog/writing-woocommerce-extensions/) by *Steve Grunwell*, to load WooCommerce as a development dependency:

```
$ composer require --dev --prefer-source woocommerce/woocommerce
```

where he mentioned doing some `composer.json` adjustments, like moving WooCommerce under the vendor path:

```
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "vendor/{$vendor}/{$name}": [
        "woocommerce/woocommerce"
      ]
    }
  }
```

and include WooCommerce tests in the generated autoloader:

```
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "vendor/woocommerce/woocommerce/tests/framework"
    ]
  },
```

followed with:

```
$ composer update
```

Then there are corresponding adjustments to the bootstrap file, as described in the article.

The [WooCommerce Custom Orders Table](https://github.com/liquidweb/woocommerce-custom-orders-table) plugin on GitHub,  from *Liquid Web*, is a great example of such a plugin.

This test setup worked well for my little WooCommerce depending plugin to be able extend the `WC_Unit_Test_Case` test class from WooCommerce.

Comment: Thanks very much for your guidance. I was able to get the tests working, but unfortunately there is no way to preserve the `--prefer-source` flag in `composer.lock`, so whenever I push to CI, the build fails. I'll have to find another method.

Comment: I haven't test if https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install has any affect, guess not. Just for reference here's the the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/liquidweb/woocommerce-custom-orders-table/blob/develop/.travis.yml) of the WooCommerce Custom Orders Table plugin.

Comment: That worked! Sweet!